# How to maintain binding on Fragment -> Intent -> Back to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using a Fragment and within my Fragment, I am starting a `new Intent` to access the device's settings. When I select the 'Back' button from the Android device, my bindings do not reflect in my View. The ViewModel properties are correct when I debug but the View doesn't reflect live data updates anymore. This only happens when I open the `Intent`

I am opening the Intent here:

```
private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

I am using the `ObservableFields` in my ViewModel so I think it's working correctly as I mentioned before - the data is correct on the debugger, just not reflected in the View if I go into the `Intent`. The View will reflect any changes if I do not go into the `Intent`. Do I need to Override the `onResume method`?

Answer (score 0):

As the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField) says,

> the fields should be declared final in your data model because bindings only detect changes in the field's value, not of the field itself

Please check this statement. If if didn't fix your problem, can you post some additionnal code as your data model class, and how you use it in your fragment?

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry then, but I don't have enough information to solve your problem